# Manhua about a teenager who sees a man practicing sword fighting in his dreams, which prompts him to start practicing sword fighting himself

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I would like to the name of the manhua. The description of the manhua is as follows:

The main character (MC) is a teenager whose father is a lord and the MC has a kind stepmother and a tsundere stepsister. The MC always sleeps. Then a man comes to a village, rents a house, and starts practicing sword fighting for the rest of the file ("Pre-sequel of the story").

This same man appears in the MC's dreams and starts practicing sword fighting in his dreams, prompting the MC to wake up and start practicing sword fighting himself. Then an old man sees him practicing and recommends him to a sword fighting school, in which he befriends the top candidate, who is a girl, and his rivals are a boy and another girl.

In the final exam they conduct, everyone is asked to show their sword fighting style and the MC simply does a vertical slash and breaks a building. Meanwhile the MC's stepsister becomes a powerful mage, and then a cat comes along, saying he is an extraordinary species, and teaches the MC about magic, during which the MC goes into a coma for a few months.

That's all that I remember. If anyone knows the name of the manhua kindly do tell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like ***[The Lazy Lord Masters the Sword](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=182180)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> After witnessing the shocking death of his mother, young Airen Farreira uses sleep to escape his painful reality, earning him the nickname, “the lazy lord”. Yet, in spite of others’ jeers and whispers, Airen has no intention of changing his ways. But when he awakens one day from a dream about a mysterious swordsman, his life’s trajectory takes a complete turn...

The story begins with a villager writing in his diary about a mysterious man who settled in his village and religiously practiced sword fighting every day for 37 years, until he collapsed and died. Then a teenage boy wakes up in bed, having just dreamed all that.

The boy, [Airen Farreira](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/airen-farreira), is the firstborn son of a baron, but is nicknamed the 'lazy lord', as he's done nothing but sleep all day since losing his biological mother at an early age. He now has a kind stepmother, and an ill-tempered stepsister, named [Kiril](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/kiril-farreira), who's also a sorcerer.

After his dream, Airen can't get back to sleep and feels restless, his body craving action. He decides to take up swordsmanship, and heads to his family's training hall to practice, picking a huge sword off the wall, just like the one he saw the man in his dream wielding.

He practices alone for the next two weeks, and finds it gruelling, as his body isn't used to this sort of exertion, but presses on regardless. An elderly knight looking on is impressed by his determination, and recommends him to a prestigious swordsmanship academy.

The top student at the academy is an aloof, noble girl named [Illia](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/illia-lindsay), and the second and third best are a tomboyish, common girl named [Judith](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/judith-the-lazy-lord-masters-the-sword), and a cocky, noble boy named [Brett](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/brett-lloyd).

The first few months of training are focused on exercise rather than swordsmanship. Airen is much weaker than the other students, but trains hard, and Illia advises him on how to lift weights correctly. Over time, his fitness improves dramatically.

After four months, the students begin swordsmanship training with wooden swords. Airen is ranked the lowest of all the students, but gradually works his way up, with Judith assisting as a practice partner.

After 12 months, the students undergo their final evaluation, in which they're to be judged on their potential. Airen states his intention to demonstrate his potential with a vertical slash, to the bemusement of the other students.

To everyone's shock though, Airen performs a vertical slash so powerful that it opens up a huge rift in the ground in front of him.

Later in the story, Airen meets a talking cat sorcerer, named [Lulu](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/lulu-the-lazy-lord-masters-the-sword), who offers to take Airen on as his student, and sends him into a mystical dream-state, enabling him to explore his own heart.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: For what it is worth, I also remember reading the manhua online under the name 'The Lazy Prince'. It started with the MC being called Erin and then retconned into Airen due to translation issues (from the source I read it at)